# after() with additional arguments not working as expected

Tags: jquery, arguments

Here's the incriminated code :

```
var openDiv = '<div class="vc_row-full-width vc_clearfix"></div><div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_row-has-fill" style="padding:1em 0 0 0"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper"><div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element" style="margin-bottom:0"><div class="wpb_wrapper"><div class="sharing"><span>Share this post:</span>';
var social = '<span>FB</span>';
var closeDiv = '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>';
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    jQuery(".splash").after(openDiv, social, closeDiv);
});
```

It displays nicely what's in openDiv and closeDiv but what's in social is diplayed outside those divs... i get the right count of closing tags, don't understand why it happens.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you can only append elements as a whole. The HTML renderer is automatically adding in the closing tags you're missing from the HTML strings, so the content of `social` appears outside of where you're expecting it.

To fix this simply concatenate all the strings before you append them:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
  $(".splash").after(openDiv + social + closeDiv);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When a string start with a `<`, jQuery handle it as a DOM node element. So the problem in your code is that jQuery think you are inserting 3 DOM node elements at once. But it is not the case. You are inserting one html code separate in 3 variables.

Try to replace with this code:

```
jQuery(".splash").after(openDiv + social + closeDiv);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you have a bit mistake at here

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
     jQuery(".splash").after(openDiv+ social+ closeDiv);
});
```

Comment: glad to help you!